# Chrome Extensions: chrome.webNavigation fails to update URL

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was trying to replace "com" ending url's with "com." as a test but it fails to run.

```js
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(function (obj) {
    var tabId = obj.tabId;
    var url = obj.url;
    if (url.indexOf(".com") < 0) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabId, { url: url.replace('.com', '.com.') });
    }

}, { url: [{ urlContains: 'com' }] });
```

Comment: What is the `0` in the last line?

Comment: @ferhen that would be my typo while pasting this code, Sorry. I'll edit that out

Comment: 1) `replace` won't do anything because the `if` condition is true when there's no `.com`. 2) Redirection is best performed with chrome.webRequest by returning redirectUrl, see the documentation and examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm for the first, i replaced it with "!= -1" and, after reloading the extension, it endlessly 'buffers'/ doesn't load the ".com" webpage

Comment: That's because it goes into an infinite loop. Use devtools to debug your code and you'll see you need another check for `.com.`.